# Unreachable code detected after transaction

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, unreachable-code

I'm getting the warning 'Unreachable code detected' in my typescript file. Nothing works after running a Firebase transaction. Here's the transaction code:

```js
// Create Firestore reference
let pointsRef = 'Users/'+this.user.uid;
var pointsDocRef = this.afs.doc(pointsRef).ref;

return this.afs.firestore.runTransaction((transaction) => {
  return transaction.get(pointsDocRef).then((ptsDoc) => {
    if(!ptsDoc.exists){
      throw "Document does not exist!"
    }

    var newPtsScore = ptsDoc.data().points - 20;
    transaction.update(pointsDocRef, { points: newPtsScore });             
  });
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Point count successfully decremented for new item'); 
  // Close dialog
  this.dialog.closeAll();
}).catch(function(error) {console.log('Transaction failed: ', error);});

console.log('Hey there!'); <-- "UNREACHABLE CODE DETECTED"
```

[image]

Comment: You have a return just above : return this.afs....

Answer (score 5):

Your log line is immediately after a `return` statement.  It line will never run because `return` leaves the function.

Comment: Which return statement?

Comment: The one at the same column as the log line.  The first one.  The second one within a different function.

Comment: @FiringBlanks `return this.afs.firestore 5])...` is all one return, then you're trying to print after the function has returned.

Comment: That's how a transaction is done according to the docs. Does this mean that every file can only have one transaction and no code after it?

Comment: @FiringBlanks Do you have to return the result of `runTransaction`?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), yes.